# Buttons with transparent blurred background

Tags: css, button

I don't know how to create the css class code for some kind of buttons that have rounded corners and transparent blurred background like iOS7 has .
Example image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3mLR.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *you can't*, at least not in any dynamic, cross-browser compatible way (unless you're only blurring SVGs, and even then support is dubious). Firefox has no analog to `-webkit-filter: blur();` and, if I recall correctly, to achieve anything similar in IE or Opera would mean a bunch of browser-specific hacks.

`filter` suggests we're moving toward the day when such things are possible, but until then, only a static workaround is possible in pure CSS. (For a JavaScript alternative, [BlurJS](http://blurjs.com/) has worked well for me before, but it also has its limitations.)

One way, if you also want the page's background blurred, is to create your blurred background in Photoshop, set it to your `body` or whatever `div`, then style your buttons like this:

```
button {
    /* For your border-radius: */
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* This will offer the illusion that it's adopting the
    background beneath it as its own but lightening it --
    almost like IOS. */
    background: #fff;
    opacity: .4;
}

/* Then maybe something like */
button:active {
    background: #000;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

But maybe you want your original background image in focus with a blurred button over it. Well, if you know your button will always be at the same distance Npx from the top of the window, and you know your button's height will always be, say, `60px`, you can cut a **full-width** `60px` tall horizontal strip from your background image at Npx from the top of the blurred image. Then set them both to something like:

```
.backgroundDiv {
    background: url('path/to/my/originalImage.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 }

.button {
    background: url('path/to/my/blurredImage.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

These are the building blocks of how you'd go about doing it; likely some combination of these and JS can achieve the ideal aesthetic. Caveat emptor, though: too many large images is no good for load time.

Answer (score -2):

You can obtain rounded corners by for example:

```
border-radius: 5px
```

You can read more about border-radius here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

For transparency and blur, you can use `-webkit-filter` in webkit browsers. See the examples: https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Comment: I was asking for blurred background of button not the entire button.

Comment: Well if -webkit-filter isn't good for you, you can always create a blurred (or with any kind of effect you like) background in photoshop or similar program, and set it as a `background-image` of this button.